# Ajax : Why success displays 0?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I use ajax with jquery and when I tried to display the result in popup.
Then alert always displays `0`

```
success : function(results) { 
alert(results); }
```

EDIT :

> ```
>  var dataToSend = {
>     action:"ACTION_NAME",
>     id : "12"
>   };
>   url_action = 'http://www.______.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
>   $.ajax({
>           url: url_action,
>           type:'POST',
>           data: dataToSend,
>           success:function(results)
>           {
>              alert(results);
>           }
>    });
> ```

Comment: probably because the result is 0. We'd need to see the code that the ajax request calls and what parameters are sent to it. What exactly do you exoect to retrun?

Comment: You can't use AJAX for cross domain request like this. Send server side request instead.

Comment: @frictionless @Darin Request : action `ACTION_NAME` and id `12` — Response `blablabla 0` — HTML `blablabla 0`— Yep, the same origin policy

Comment: @Shadow What do you mean ? My script works, but at the end, it displays ALWAYS 0. Whatever I do.

Comment: You mean there **is** a response, but `0` always get appended to it?

Comment: To see : [http://wordpress.org/support/topic/trailing-zero-with-admin-ajax-calls](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/trailing-zero-with-admin-ajax-calls) — I have exactly the same problem, but `die('0')` doesn't work.

Comment: @Shadow Yep, exactly.  `0` always get appended to the result !

Comment: @Steffi OK, the `die('0')` is the command appending that zero. Add `die()` in the end of your own function and according to the post you posted it should eliminate the zero.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try to add `die();` or `exit();` at the very last line of the function.

Answer (score 13):

May be you are trying without login. so you need to use this action.

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

you will get response. :)

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue with admin-ajax.php returning 0, even i had die().

My problem was that the add_action was declared in a file not loaded default by plugin.

Anyway, if you have problem also check in browser what __.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=youraction returns.

Comment: it won't return if it's a post request, mart

Comment: I had the same issue where it wasn't in a file loaded by default.

Answer (score 7):

Found it.

It need to add `die();` before the end of my own ajax function in `function.php`.

Because there is one line of script in `admin-ajax.php` after my own ajax_action that says: die('0'); So we need to **die()** script before die('0').

Answer (score 5):

I was adding the "action" incorrectly. You have to prefix your action with `wp_ajax_gd_`.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_gd_[ACTION NAME]', '[CALLBACK FUNCTION NAME]')
```

and in the JS jQuery post:

```
var data = {
    'action': '[ACTION NAME]',
};
```

I found Wordpress' documentation very unclear about this part.

Answer (score 3):

That's probably because the server side script you are calling with AJAX returns `0` (the one you have specified in the `url` property).

Comment: @Steffi, so when you look with [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) what exactly is sent as request and as response fro the server? Are you sure that you have respected the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)?

Comment: Request : action `ACTION_NAME` and id `12` — Response `blablabla 0` — HTML `blablabla 0`— Yep, the same origin policy

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the action_name is ok.  If it's not found in functions.php you will get 0 as the result.

Answer (score 2):

In your PHP function, make sure you're using `echo` instead of `return`.

This was happening for me in a WordPress theme.

```
function doAjax() {
    $result = getPosts();
    echo json_encode($result, true);
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I'd forgotten to enable the plugin. After enabling the plugin I received the expected data.

Comment: +1 Wow just had the same issue. Can't believe this was the problem (*bangs head against desk*)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `die();` at the end of your function can solve it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Those who get error 0 :), action => 'action'

```
var data = {'action': 'my_action', 'data': form_data };

$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) { alert(response);});
```

Comment: The code in the question shows that they are setting `action` already