# JQuery Form only submits in certain browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm working on a registration form for my website and it is only working in Firefox (with some issues), but in Chrome it does not work at all.

For example, if I correctly fill out the form in Firefox and submit, the PHP page still loads instead of sending that content to my registration form via my ajax call.  However in Chrome, the form doesn't appear to submit at all.

In fact, in Chrome the variable `data` is set to the `$num` value in my PHP script, which is then displayed in `#modal-body`.

**Question:** How can I get this to work in all browsers and why is my `event.preventdefault()` not working correctly for Firefox??
 
Here is my registration form submission code:

```
$('#register-form').submit(function() {
    $('#register-form > .input-group').removeClass('has-error');

    $('#register-form .form-required').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().trim() == "") {
            empty = true;
            $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
            errors = "<strong>You have not filled out the login form correctly.</strong>";
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error');
            $(this).parent().addClass('has-success');
        }
    });

    // All fields populated, process the form
    if (!empty) {
        $('.progress').fadeIn(800);
        $('#modal-body').parent().removeClass("has-error");

        var formData = {
            'username'  : $('input[name=usernameReg]').val(),
            'email'     : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'password'  : $('input[name=passwordReg]').val()
        };

        // Process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url         : 'db.php', 
            data        : formData, 
            dataType    : 'json', 
            encode      : true,
            success     : function(data) {

                if (data) {

                // Fade the resulting message in
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".progress").fadeOut(1000);
                        $("#modal-body").fadeIn(1000);
                        $("#modal-body").html(data);
                    }, 1000);

                    // Fade the resulting message out
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#modal-body").fadeOut(2000);
                    }, 3000);
                }

                else {
                    $('#modal-body').addClass('has-error'); 
                    $('#modal-body').html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // There were empty fields on the form
    else {
        $('#modal-body').html(errors);
    }
    event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Here is my PHP code that handles processing of the form and checking to make sure that the account does not already exist, then that it is created in the database:

```
            $hashed = md5($salt.$_POST['passwordReg']);
            $email    = $_POST['email'];

            // Check if account already exists
            $username = strtolower($_POST['usernameReg']);
            $statement = $conn->prepare($selects['username']);
            $statement->bind_param('ss', $hashed, $username);

            if ($statement->execute()) {
                //$statement->bind_result($results);
                $num;
                while($statement->fetch()){
                    $num++;
                }
                $statement->free_result();
            }
            else {
                trigger_error('Error executing MySQL query: ' . $statement->error);
            }

            $statement = null;

            // If num > 0, account exists. 
            // printf($num) only present for debugging purposes
            printf($num);
            if ($num < 1) {
                $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `User` (username, email, password) VALUES(?,?,?)");
                $statement->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $hashed);

                if ($statement->execute()) {
                    echo json_encode('You have registered successfully');
                }
                else {
                    echo json_encode('Sorry, registration failed. Please try again later.');
                }
            }
            else {
                echo json_encode('Sorry, registration failed. Please verify that you do not already have an account.');
            }
        break;
```

Comment: Try putting the `event.preventDefault()` at the top of the callback.  The browser may be hitting the PHP script before it gets to the end of the function.

Comment: Simple error: `event` is undefined.

Comment: @searsaw I tried this, but the results were the same :(

Comment: @epascarello How can I define this event?

Comment: `.submit(function(event) {` <-- Just like the answer below suggests

Answer (score 2):

Pass the event into the callback

```
$('#register-form').submit(function(e) {
 // your code...
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but now the form does not work in either browser.

Comment: No errors, I receive a response code of 200 and a response of '0'

Comment: Is your printf still in your php? Maybe $num is zero

Comment: I commented it out, $num should contain the value zero for the registration to work; any other value indicates that an account already exists for the given email.  However, I have nothing that should be returning 0.

Comment: Sounds like your javascript is working right. Trace through your php script and make sure all of your $_POST params and variables are being set properly

Comment: Make sure it isn't something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371393/ajax-why-success-displays-0

Comment: I attempted to put this line in both my Javascript and in my PHP, but still getting return value of 0.   I don't know why it's working in Firefox, but not in chrome.

Comment: I am getting an error on line 21: $_POST ['username'] is undefined. But I'm not using that variable anyways.  Could that be the problem?