# JS adds a zero at the end

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

On my jQuery ajax function, I output the data returned from a PHP script like this:

```
jQuery(this).html(data);
```

The PHP function which returns the data contains:

```
echo 'Please do this again.';
return;
```

By some reason, it outputs as:

> Please do this again.0

So it adds a `0` at the end. Why does this happen and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Could you update question with result of `console.log(data);`

Comment: ok what is the output when you open php file directly?show php relevant codes

Comment: The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @salih It shows `Please try again.0` on console for `data`

Comment: @nicael Is the problem elsewhere in the JS file or PHP function?

Comment: remove `return` from php

Comment: @Jeff I need to run return to stop executing the rest of the function in that part.

Comment: @Jeff Yes, exist works. Can you please write up an answer as to why this works in this case?

Comment: @nicael I can assure you that the rest of my code is totally irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: remove anything outside php tag

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371393/ajax-why-success-displays-0

Comment: I bet you're using WordPress :)

Comment: @JonSurrell Yes, how could you tell? How is this related to WP?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson WordPress ajax actions print a `0` at the end if you don't end execution in your handler (with `die` for example). You can see this by inspecting the php file which handles ajax calls. From memory, something like `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, but that might be way off.

Comment: @JonSurrell That's right, it has `die('0')` -- WordPress at its finest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

You should `die` inside of your ajax action handler as follows:

```
echo 'Please do this again.';
// Don't return, die!
// return;
die;
```

## Explanation

Your code is performing exactly as expected. The problem is that you're using WordPress and have not stopped execution inside of your action handler function.

WordPress handles ajax calls via `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, and the [last lines](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d7253ca244068c16acc1ca0b5c01359b32911433/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php#L103-L104) will produce the output `0`:

```
// Default status
die( '0' );
```

Inside of your action handler function, you should call `die` yourself to ensure that the end of this file is never reached and `0` is not appended to your response.

Answer (score 2):

Quick Answer (I will explain more later):

With `return;` you produce that extra output, that gets interpreted to `0`.

Eighter remove that `return;` or replace it with an `exit;` to stop php from executing.

Other possibility is to do `return 'Please do this again.';` if you are outside of functions.